# Regular expression for subpattern match

Tags: javascript, regex

I want regular expression which return true if any continuous three charters match.
For e.g `/[money]{3,}/g`
It return true for mon, one, ney and return false for mny.

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: Why can't you do this `/(?:mon|one|ney)/g` ?

Comment: Using a regex here is pointless (and a mess if you want it to be dynamic), use indexOf('mon') !== -1 instead.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: If live validation is meant: `/(m(?:on?)?|o(?:ne?)?|n(?:ey?)?/`. Anyway, the question is way too unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex, why not use `indexOf`, it's less code and better to read.

something like `"money".indexOf("mon")>-1`

**Here a Demo, with all listed examples:**

```js
let values = ["mon","one", "ney", "mny"];
let shouldMatch = "money";

for (let idx = 0; idx<values.length;idx++){
    console.info(values[idx], "=", shouldMatch.indexOf(values[idx])>-1);
}
```

***But*** If you want to use **RegExp**, you could use it like this:
*(BTW: this is only a "fancy" way to write the example above)*

```js
let values = ["mon","one", "ney", "mny"];


function matcher(word, value){
    return (new RegExp(value)).test(word);
}

for (let idx = 0; idx<values.length;idx++){
    console.info(values[idx], "=", matcher("money", values[idx]));
}
```

> **The Code Basically:**
>
> Creates a new Regular Expression exp. `(new RegExp("mon"))` *(equal to  `/mon/`)* and than just testing, if the "pattern" matches the word `"money"` `(new RegExp("mon")).test("money")` this returns `true`.
>
> Here it is all turned around, we are checking if **money** fits into the *(sub)*-pattern **mon**.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions function as a search for a character string, your application would require taking a base string and dynamically building an insane regex with many ORs and lookaheads/behinds.  For your application, write a function that uses `indexOf`

```
function stringContainsSubstr(sourceStr, subStr) {
  return sourceStr.indexOf(subStr) !== -1;
}

var exampleStrs = ["mon", "one", "ney", "mny"];
var str = "money";

for (var i = 0; i < exampleStrs.length; i++) {
  console.log(stringContainsSubstr(str, exampleStrs[i]));
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2mtV1NeD1MYta5v49oWr